# How can I add 'main/dist-upgrader-all' to '/etc/apt/mirror.list' so that my apt-mirror downloads the files for a release upgrade?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, apt-mirror

I maintain an apt mirror by using [`apt-mirror`](https://apt-mirror.github.io/). It works fine for the packages of *bionic* and *focal*. Now, I want to add the files, that are needed to be able to perform release upgrades using this mirror. In `/etc/apt/mirror.list` I added `main/dist-upgrader-all` to all update sources that contain these folders.

My `/etc/apt/mirror.list` currently looks like this:

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /mnt/usb/ubuntu_mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse main/dist-upgrader-all
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse main/dist-upgrader-all
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse main/dist-upgrader-all
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse main/dist-upgrader-all
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

After the addition of `main/dist-upgrader-all`, the execution of `apt-mirror` throws the following errors, when processing indexes:

```
Downloading 352 index files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  2 12:15:38 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Aug  2 12:16:01 2021

Processing translation indexes: [TTTTTTTT]

Downloading 1137 translation files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  2 12:16:03 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Aug  2 12:16:26 2021

Processing DEP-11 indexes: [DDDDDDDD]

Downloading 160 dep11 files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Aug  2 12:16:29 2021
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Aug  2 12:16:35 2021

Processing indexes: [Papt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/bionic/main/dist-upgrader-all/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
PPapt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
PPapt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/focal/main/dist-upgrader-all/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
PPapt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
P]
```

So, what am I doing wrong? How can I successfully add the files from `main/dist-upgrader-all` to my mirror, so that clients using this mirror can perform release upgrades?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am in the same boat. I keep finding docs about using deb-mirror to do this, but nothing for doing it with apt-mirror. The one thing I did so far was add the meta files needed as well adding this bionic-proposed to my local mirror.

Comment: @TimR No, as a workaround, additionally to `apt-mirror`, I execute a script with several `wget` commands that download the necessary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dist-upgrader-all` directory is not an apt repository, but it can be mirrored by apt-mirror by using the `postmirror.sh` script.

Here are lines that can be added to the `postmirror.sh` script to mirror the `dist-upgrader-all` directory for focal.  The `postmirror.sh` script runs in the `$base_path/mirror` directory and relative paths are used.

```
mkdir -p archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dist-upgrader-all/
rsync --recursive --times --links --hard-links --delete --delete-after rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dist-upgrader-all/ archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dist-upgrader-all/
```

Using rsync is a technique shown in the sample `postmirror.sh` script [in the apt-mirror repository](https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/blob/6c11ce93966143d5c2df5b45a43ee8912a8f1575/postmirror.sh).  It shows that rsync can be used to mirror various extra directories in an apt repository, including the `debian-installer`, `dist-upgrader-all`, `installer-amd64`, and `installer-i386` paths.